# Can' locate a certain element using xpath locator in python

Tags: python, xpath

I've written an `xpath` to get to a certain element but unfortunately it is not being able to.

I can't understand where i'm getting deviated. Hope somebody will provide me with a little help.

I'm trying to locate the address from the below elements.

Here are the elements:

```
<div class="detail-contact-address">
   <i class="fa fa-map-o"></i> 
   Address:36 Sukhumvit, Soi 15, Wattana, Klongtoey-nua, Bangkok 10110, Thailand
</div>
```

I was trying with:

```
//div[@class='detail-contact-address']/*[contains(@class,'fa-map-o')]/../text()
```

Comment: Do you want to match some text in this address or just want to get whole text ?

Comment: The whole text will do. I tried with string match as well but didn't worked out.

Comment: not working means? where you getting issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User below xpath to get the text :

```
//div[@class='detail-contact-address']
```

OR based on some string match

```
//div[@class='detail-contact-address'][contains(.,'Address')]
```

So you will get the text like

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='detail-contact-address']").text
```

Comment: Thanks Tuks, for your answer. Your second solution worked out this way "//div[@class='detail-contact-address']/text()[contains(.,'Address:')]"